# simple bar chart ggplot2 numerical labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to ggplot and having difficulty creating a simple bar chart.  My data is already binned and I would simply like to recreate a bar chart

```
x freq
2   10
7   18 
9   10
18  90
```

I would like the x axis to use the x data as labels without "scaling" the data, essentially, I think I am trying to do a `scale_identity` but having trouble figuring it out.  I got this far:

```
qplot(x=V1, y=V2, data=test, geom="bar", stat="identity", color="red")
```

Comment: I ended up doing test$V1 <- as.character(test$V1) and that did it. Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: If your `x`/`V1` represent labels, not numerical values, then using `qplot(x=factor(V1), ...` or `qplot(x=as.character(V1), ...` will work.